# Xamarin.iOS MvvmCross, gives error in AppDelegate System.TypeInitializationException?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, mvvmcross

[image]

I have selected the linker correctly (i.e. Framework SDK Only) but still, it raises this error, it stops the app from here.

the NuGet package used: MvvMCross (6.0.1), MvvMCross.Core (5.7.0), MvvMCross.Binding(5.7.0), MvvMCross.Platform(5.7.0)

Comment: Remove the 5.7.0 packages they are not compatible with 6.0.1

Comment: Then which version I have to use @Cheesebaron

Comment: why this incompatibility issue with the latest version? @Cheesebaron

Comment: All packages need to be the same version. If you read the release notes for 6.0.0 you would have noticed that Core, Bindings and Platform NuGet packages have been deprecated and no longer need to be added to the project. Just MvvmCross package is enough.

Comment: I have read that but when I'm using the package mvvmcross only its not working as it has to. It asks for installing that three package separately. @Cheesebaron

Comment: the MvvmCross samples on git are with the old version, can you please let me know how to get the samples with 6.0 version with xamarin ios solution. Thanks for answers! @Cheesebaron

Comment: If you are using a 3rd party plugin, you should ask the author to update their plugin to latest MvvmCross.

Comment: I have not used any 3rd party plugin, I have sent you a mail can you please check it. @Cheesebaron

Comment: Please keep the discussion here at StackOverflow or if you believe it is a bug, then open an issue on GitHub.

Comment: Ok, thanks for help @Cheesebaron